# why return type of getInstance method should be return by reference?

Tags: c++, singleton

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    private :
        A()
        {
            cout<<"Constructed"<<endl;
        }
        ~A()
        {
            cout<<"Destructed"<<endl;
        }
    public:
        static A& getInstance()
        {
            static A a;
            return a;
        }
};

int main()
{
    A::getInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

why return type of getInstance method should be return by reference ?

Iam getting below error if return type of getInstance method is return by value .

```
.\2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\2.cpp:25:20: error: 'A::~A()' is private within this context
   25 |     A::getInstance();
      |                    ^
.\2.cpp:11:9: note: declared private here
   11 |         ~A()
      |         ^
```

Comment: Hint: This design pattern is called a Singleton.

Comment: Return by value copies. Singletons are designed to have at most one instance so cannot be copied.

Comment: Handy reading: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few more additions:

The return type doesn't have to be a reference, but since the destructor of the class you are returning is private, any function (not this specific one) which returns an object of that type cannot return the actual object.

This is because the caller cannot make a copy of that object. When passed by value, a copy of the object is created, and returned back (there are more optimizations on this but this is the simplest idea). The caller then destroys that object when it gets out of scope, if it is private, the caller cannot.

One more quick note on returning references, when you return a reference, the caller is not responsible for the lifetime of the object. If you destroy the returned object, before the caller is done with it, you might end up in an access violation to uninitialized (destroyed) memory. In your example, this is not possible because the returned object is a static object which will live until the end of the application, so this pattern is good if that is your intention, and as also mentioned in some comments, it is called the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> why return type of getInstance method should be return by reference?

Because the destructor is private, as pointed out by the diagnostic message. When the destructor is private, no temporary objects can be created outside the scope of the class. If you call a function that returns a prvalue and discard that value, a temporary object will be created.

You've tagged the question as [singleton]. A singleton is a class of which only one object exists. If your function returns a new object for each call, then it won't be a singleton.